# Gradle Maven Publish plugin: how to upload files with arbitrary names without artifactId?

Tags: gradle, artifactory, gradle-kotlin-dsl, maven-publish

I have a project for which I have to upload YAML files into artifactory. I want them to be located at a specific path in artifactory, but I want to determine the full name myself without the artifactId present in the name.

### What I have

```
plugins {
    `maven-publish`
}

group = "com.example"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
}

// Example task for generating YAML files.
tasks.register("generateSomething") {
    doLast {
        buildDir.resolve("generated").mkdir()
        buildDir.resolve("generated/my-st-$version.yml").writeText("I am file for ST")
        buildDir.resolve("generated/my-prd-$version.yml").writeText("I am file for PRD")
    }
}

project.tasks.withType(AbstractPublishToMaven::class.java) {
    dependsOn("generateSomething")
}

publishing {
    publications {
        create<MavenPublication>("my-own-artifacts") {
            artifact(buildDir.resolve("generated/my-st-$version.yml")) {
                classifier = "st"
                extension = "$version.txt"
            }
            artifact(buildDir.resolve("generated/my-prd-$version.yml")) {
                classifier = "prd"
                extension = "$version.txt"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run `gradle publishToMavenLocal` (artifactId is test-example), I get the following files inside `repository\com\example\test-example\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\`.

```
test-example-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-prd.0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.yml
test-example-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-st.0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.yml
```

But what I want is:

```
prd.0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.yml
st.0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.yml
```

### What I tried

I have tried changing the artifactId to `my-st`, but this leads to the path changing to `com\example\my-set\...`, which is not what I want. I also tried playing around with classifier and extension, but it always prefixes the name with things I don't want.

I don't see any other methods I have available in the MavenPublish class.

I checked the code in `AbstractMavenPublisher.java`, and it may be that it is not possible at all:

```
        /**
         * Publishes a single module artifact, based on classifier and extension.
         */
        void publish(String classifier, String extension, File content) {
            StringBuilder path = new StringBuilder(128);
            path.append(groupPath).append('/');
            path.append(artifactId).append('/');
            path.append(moduleVersion).append('/');
            path.append(artifactId).append('-').append(artifactVersion);

            if (classifier != null) {
                path.append('-').append(classifier);
            }
            if (extension.length() > 0) {
                path.append('.').append(extension);
            }

            ExternalResourceName externalResource = new ExternalResourceName(rootUri, path.toString());
            publish(externalResource, content);
        }
```

But I am not sure if this is the code that is actually called. Maybe there are other ways to publish?